# Dispose forms in circle around a bigger form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, searchbar

I want to realize a search bar, with other mini search bars around her

the code of the search bar would be similar as

```
<form >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..."  name="searchbox" >
      <button class="searchbutton" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

the disposition would be like [image]

any tips to do this, css3, html5, js or jquery nice accepted!

then i want to move them inside when i click one of the "around" search bar, like:

[image]

maybe using http://visionmedia.github.com/move.js/ plug in, well if someone have tips also for this would be really interesting

thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd start by looking for a circular carousel that allows elements (divs etc.) as well as images.

Comment: That's a nice idea but it's not exactly what i want to realize.
My vision is a 2D movements